# Como puedo seguir la secuencia de búsqueda por medio de la primera letra en la lista con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lista, select

Tengo el siguiente código:

[HTML]

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected">Alemán</li>
  <li>Español Argentina</li>
  <li>Español Perú</li>
  <li>Frances</li>
  <li>Ingles</li>
  <li>Italiano</li>
</ul>
```

[CSS]

```
ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #777;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

li:hover,
li.selected {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
```

[JS]

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
  let chars = "";
  let list = Array.from(ul.querySelectorAll("li"));

  document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    chars = e.key.toLowerCase();

    console.log(chars);

    let regex = new RegExp("^" + chars, "i");

    list
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach((option) => {
        if (regex.test(option.textContent) === true) {
          ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((options) => {
            options.classList.remove("selected");
          });
          option.classList.add("selected");
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Al presionar cualquier tecla activa el evento keyup, busca por la primera letra en la lista y selecciona el texto deseado, hasta aquí todo bien

**Problema:**

Al presionar la tecla **"e"** selecciona **"Español Argentina"**

Pero al presionar la tecla **"e"** por segunda vez no baja a **"Español Perú"**

Espero puedan ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías brindar un contador al pulsar determinada letra y al cambiar la letra resetear dicho contador, me explico, disponer de un array que contenga la búsqueda de resultados de una letra inicial en especifico y después si dicha letra tiene un contador mayor a 1 o N que lo busque en el array fltrado.

Comment: Te he agregado el código que define mi último comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ha agredado las variables :

- LastLetter
- Contador

Estás variables controlan cuál ha sido la última letra pulsada y el número de veces.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
          const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
          let chars = "";
          let list = Array.from(ul.querySelectorAll("li"));
        
          let lastLetter;
          let contador = 0;
          
          document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
            chars = e.key.toLowerCase();
            if ( lastLetter !== undefined && chars === lastLetter) {
              contador++;
            } else {
              lastLetter = chars;
              contador = 0;
            }
        
            let regex = new RegExp("^" + chars, "i");
            let filtrado = list.filter((v)=>{
              return regex.test(v.textContent);
            })
          
             //Limpiar selected
            ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((options) => {
                    options.classList.remove("selected");
              });
            //Asignar selected
            if ( filtrado[contador] !== undefined ) {
              filtrado[contador].classList.add('selected');  
            } else {
              //Se mantiene en el último
              contador--;
              filtrado[contador].classList.add('selected');  
            }
          });
        });
```

```css
ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #777;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

li:hover,
li.selected {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="selected">Alemán</li>
  <li>Español Argentina</li>
  <li>Español Perú</li>
  <li>Frances</li>
  <li>Ingles</li>
  <li>Italiano</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tremenda solución :D